# Problem running in Jekyll. Installation

Tags: jekyll

I have installed Ruby, RubyGems and then Jekyll, but when I run Jekyll I'm getting this error.

```
$ jekyll serve
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in `require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/filters.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:43
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/jekyll:7
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
somasundaram@somasundaram-Inspiron-3521:~/allfiles/msomu/msomu.github.io$ ^C
somasundaram@somasundaram-Inspiron-3521:~/allfiles/msomu/msomu.github.io$ jekyll/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in `require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/filters.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:43
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/jekyll:7
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
```

Also if there is no way to fix it please help me if someone tells me how to completely remove Ruby, RubyGems Jekyll and fresh install it or fix this error.

Comment: So are you on a mac? Did you install xcode command line tools?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Dell

Comment: Did you run "jekyll build" first?

Comment: Same problem on Centos 6.4, will come back here if I find something.

Comment: To solve this error I have reinstalled ruby completely, using RVM this time.

I'm on centos but I'll write a summary of the commands I've ran, that could be useful to someone:

    `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

    `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh // this can change`

    `rvm requirements`

    `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353`

   `rvm use 2.0.0 --default`

    `rvm rubygems current`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you and after installing the JSON gem by `sudo gem install json` I had no problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788258/error-when-running-jekyll-new-command